# Eliminate Windows 10 Word startup screen

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

The Word startup screen is a nuisance.  Every time a different folder is to be accessed, one has to waste time going through the startup screen.  In Excel Options, I was able to eliminate its startup screen.  Is there a way to do it with Word?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Word, Options, General.

Right Hand Side, down near the bottom, "Start up options", remove the check mark beside (so disable) "Show the Start screen when this application starts"

That works here on my Word 2016 (365).

Comment: It works on my Word 2016 also.  Edo

Answer (score 1):

*Elaborating a bit on John's answer...*

### First, the general Startup Screen

File > Options
General > Start Up Options

[image: options screenshot]

### Second, the Open and Save Background

File > Options
Save > Save Documents

[image: options screenshot]

### Then, Click on OK to save these settings.